# How to understand the phrase: "This is where it starts to get tricky."?

Tags: phrase-meaning

How to understand the phrase: "This is where it starts to get tricky."? 
or "It is where it starts to get tricky."?

Comment: It means: that is the point at which the issue becomes difficul to handle, complicated. ***Tricky***:  needing careful and tactful handling: *a tricky situation*. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tricky

Comment: A similar phrase: "Here's the tricky part"

Comment: Are you asking about the difference between "This is where" and "It is where", or about the meaning of "tricky"?

Answer (score 6):

tricky here means more difficult than what it used to be.

So this sentence means

"From this point in time the difficulty of whatever we are doing is going to be more difficult than it used to be"